# Git list all files modified (not added) since a specific commit INCLUDING ones that were added and later modified

Tags: git, powershell, git-diff, git-log

I recently started working on a project with a huge code base. I decided to create a local git repo to keep track of all my changes. Rather than downloading all the project's existing files and adding them to git. I only downloaded the ones I needed. As I needed more files, I downloaded them and added them to git.

Now the client wants me to provide a list of all files that I've changed since a particular commit.

```
git diff --diff-filter=M --name-only $last_deploy_commit_id
```

gives only the modified files that existed at that commit.

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only $last_deploy_commit_id
```

lists all files added since that commit but not (necessarily) modified later on.

```
git diff --diff-filter=AM --name-only $last_deploy_commit_id
```

lists all files added OR modified since that commit.

What I want is to have a list of all files that

- Either, already existed and were modified since that commit
- Or, didn't exist at that commit, were created AND were later modified, both since that commit.

Is there a way to do this? I'm on Windows, if that helps. I'm open to using some PowerShell based script if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `--name-status` flag to `git log` to do this, along with a
commit range `<commit>^..HEAD`:

```
$ git log --oneline 70f5c30^..HEAD --name-status
7f6aafa Add poopoo
A       poopoo.txt
1d961ae Add hello and goodbye
M       blar.txt
M       rawr.txt
0a1acf9 Add rawr
A       rawr.txt
70f5c30 Add blar moo and I'LL BE BACK!
M       README.md
A       blar.txt
```

The commit range `<commit>^..HEAD` uses an ***exclusive*** starting point,
meaning that ***it's not included***, so you have to use the parent of
`<commit>`, which is `<commit>^`. See [Pro Git: Commit Ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges).

**NOTE:** `git log` is a [porcelain command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html#_git_commands), meaning that it's not guaranteed to be backwards compatible in future versions of Git. Normally, if you want to use the output of Git commands in a script, you'd use one of the plumbing commands instead. But since this seems to be a one-time use thing, using `git log` just this once for this purpose seems like a reasonable solution.

### Filtering Out Added but Un-modified Files

After getting the output above, you could then possibly `grep` (or whatever the
Windows PowerShell equivalent of `grep` is) lines that contain `M` or `A` and
sort them, then filter out filenames where there is a line for `A`, but no line
for `M`.

I don't want to spend the time to learn enough PowerShell in order to do this,
but here's how you could filter the results if you were using a Unix environment
with Ruby:

```
$ git log --oneline <commit>^..HEAD --name-status | \
$ grep --extended-regexp "^(A|M)" | \
$ ruby ~/Desktop/stackoverflow-answer.rb
```

where `stackoverflow-answer.rb` contains the following:

```ruby
x = ARGF.map { |line| line.split("\t").map(&:chomp) }
        .each_with_object({}) do |parts, hash|
          if hash[parts.last]
            hash[parts.last] << parts.first
          else
            hash[parts.last] = [parts.first]
          end
        end
        .reject { |k,v| v.size == 1 && v.first == 'A' }
        .keys
puts x
```

Comment: Thanks. Got a modified version of this to work with Git and Ruby from Windows and grep from Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, a Powsershell command won't work in a rootGit repo folder which has been renamed.
With Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), the way the Windows port figures out the current directory has been
improved.

See [commit 4745fee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4745feeb8b501b309f2eb2e0330abd6c24d6fb60) (23 Oct 2018) by [Anton Serbulov (`skvoboo`)](https://github.com/skvoboo).
See [commit 937974f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/937974fc65f517a67bfb09086b3726e3498d65b2) (23 Oct 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cc67487](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc6748720f9014b2c2cea8a603acd9ff6a62b87c), 30 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `mingw`: fix `getcwd` when the parent directory cannot be queried
>
> `GetLongPathName()` function may fail when it is unable to query
>   the parent directory of a path component to determine the long name
>   for that component. It happens, because it uses `FindFirstFile()`
>   function for each next short part of path. The `FindFirstFile()`
>   requires `List Directory` and `Synchronize` desired access for a calling
>   process.
>
> In case of lacking such permission for some part of path,
>   the `GetLongPathName()` returns 0 as result and `GetLastError()`
>   returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.
>
> `GetFinalPathNameByHandle()` function can help in such cases, because
>   it requires `Read Attributes` and `Synchronize` desired access to the
>   target path only.
>
> The `GetFinalPathNameByHandle()` function was introduced on
>   `Windows Server 2008/Windows Vista`. So we need to load it dynamically.

That will help when doing a git log in a powershell session:

> ### `mingw`: ensure `getcwd()` reports the correct case
>
> When switching the current working directory, say, in PowerShell, it is quite possible to use a different capitalization than the one that is recorded on disk.
>   While doing the same in `cmd.exe` adjusts the capitalization magically, that does not happen in PowerShell so that `getcwd()` returns the current directory in a different way than is recorded on disk.
>
> Typically this creates no problems except when you call:
>
> ```
> git log .
> ```
>
> in a subdirectory called, say, "`GIT/`" but you switched to "`Git/`" and
>   your `getcwd()` reports the latter, then Git won't understand that you wanted to see the history as per the `GIT/` subdirectory but it thinks you wanted to see the history of some directory that may have existed in the past (but actually never did).